# Access data in asp.net attribute

Tags: asp.net, custom-attributes

Our webapp-solution needs a login preventer that gives the user a 10 seconds penalty (in where he cannot log in) after three incorrect logins.

Today this task is solved by an attribute, ToggleAttribute (custom), that contains a counter keeping track of the users number of logins attempts.

If the number exeeds the defined limit (default 3) the ToggleAttribute will redirect the user back to the login page with a 10 sec penalty.

This works OK. However, the problem occurs when the user has successfully logged in and out. The counter is not reset, so the next user gets only two login attempts.

I would like a way to reset the counter inside the attribute from our login controller if password validation is good. May I access the data in the Attribute from the controller?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was solved by putting the counter data into a cache that is aslo accessable outside of the attribute. By doing so, the login controller may reset counter. It is not a perfect solution, but works until we implement a authorization solution further up the road.